# How to get data from JSON using groupby and filter using lodash

Tags: javascript, json

I need to get only a single data from a json file, I am using lodash .groupBy and .filter but it only throws back a false result

```
let insightAverageThroughput = [{
    "insight": "wahahahah",
    "reportMonth": "June 2018",
    "project": "Cambridge Core Dashboard"
  },
  {
    "insight": "aaaaaaa",
    "reportMonth": "February 2018",
    "project": "coreadmin"
  }
];

function filterInsights(data, month, project) {
  let grouped = _.groupBy(data, z => z.project == project)
  console.log(month)
  console.log(project)
  console.log(grouped)
  let filtered = _.filter(grouped[project], x => x.reportMonth == month)
  console.log(filter)
  return filtered.length > 0 && filtered[0].insight;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `groupBy` only by project and not by predicate:

```
  let grouped = _.groupBy(data, z => z.project)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `groupBy`, all the data will be grouped by a one single project and using `filter` we will return all the items, these met the condition `reportMonth === month`.

Also please note how I used `groupBy`. You should pass a value, instead of condition:

```
_.groupBy(data, 'project')
```

**Here's the code**:

```js
let insightAverageThroughput = [{
    "insight": "wahahahah",
    "reportMonth": "June 2018",
    "project": "Cambridge Core Dashboard"
  },
  {
    "insight": "aaaaaaa",
    "reportMonth": "February 2018",
    "project": "coreadmin"
  }
];

function filterInsights(data, month, project) {
  const grouped = _.groupBy(data, 'project')
  const filteredItems = grouped[project].filter(({ reportMonth }) => reportMonth === month)
  
  return { [project]: filteredItems }
}

console.log(filterInsights(insightAverageThroughput, 'February 2018', 'coreadmin'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.2.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

The same logic, you can implement in ES6 (without external libraries). Here's how I would do it, using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) only:

```js
let insightAverageThroughput = [{
    "insight": "wahahahah",
    "reportMonth": "June 2018",
    "project": "Cambridge Core Dashboard"
  },
  {
    "insight": "aaaaaaa",
    "reportMonth": "February 2018",
    "project": "coreadmin"
  }
];

function filterInsights(data, month, project) {
  return data.reduce((accumulator, item) => { 

    if (item.project === project && month === item.reportMonth) {
      accumulator[project].push(item)
    }
    
    return accumulator
  } , { [project]: [] })
}

console.log(filterInsights(insightAverageThroughput, 'February 2018', 'coreadmin' ))
```